# Does OpenAPI allow using RFC 6570 template syntax in path templates?

Tags: parameters, openapi

I'm a little bit confused, as [swagger.io](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#uri-templates) mentions the connection between OpenAPI parameter serialization and [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) path/query template syntax. It's also mentioned in the [openapis.com](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#path-templating-matching) docs.

What I'm interested in is the exact syntax used to express OpenAPI parameters in the **path template string**.

##### A) Is it allowed (by OA spec) to use the relevant parts of RFC 6570 to substitute parameter objects?

I know that this is allowed.

```yaml
paths:
  "/test/{foo}":
    get:
      operationId: getFoo
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: foo
        required: true
        style: label
        schema:
          type: string
```

But is this? Is it equivalent to the first one?

```yaml
paths:
  # Parameters array omitted, as "." marks "foo" a "label" style parameter
  "/test/{.foo}":
    get:
      operationId: getFoo
```

##### B) In case the second example is not allowed, what's the path parameter syntax?

From the examples it looks like `{<identifier>}`, but is there anything more to this?

##### C) If it's B) (no RFC syntax in the path templates), is it always required to have a matching parameter object for `{<identifier>}`?

Meaning do I have to have as many parameter objects, as I have `{<identifier>}` in my path templates? I'm not 100% sure about the wording, but [openapis.com](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#path-templating-matching) seems to suggest this. It also mentions:

> An exception is if the path item is empty, for example due to ACL constraints, matching path parameters are not required.

What does this mean?

**My sources**:

- https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#path-templating-matching
- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#uri-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A) Is it allowed (by OA spec) to use the relevant parts of RFC 6570 to substitute parameter objects?
> B) In case the second example is not allowed, what's the path parameter syntax?
> From the examples it looks like `{<identifier>}`, but is there anything more to this?

OpenAPI supports RFC 6570 [level 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-1.2) syntax in the path template strings, that is, just `{identifier}`. OpenAPI does *not* support RFC 6570 operators and value modifiers (`+`, `*`, etc.) in its path templates. So your second example `/test/{.foo}` means the parameter name is `.foo` not `foo`.

OpenAPI analog of RFC 6570 operators and modifiers (`.`, `+`, `*`, etc.) are the [`style`](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0.html#parameterStyle) and [`explode`](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0.html#parameterExplode) keywords in parameter objects. These keywords mimic *some* types of RFC 6570 [expression expansions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2) (specifically, the simple, label, form-style, and path-style expansions). The [Serialization](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/) doc on swagger.io mentions RFC 6570 modifiers to give an idea how various `style` and `explode` combinations correspond to RFC 6570-style URI templates.

> C) If it's B) (no RFC syntax in the path templates), is it always required to have a matching parameter object for `{<identifier>}`?

Not always. According to the [Path Templating](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0.html#path-templating) section of the OpenAPI Specification, the only case when it's NOT required is if the path item object is empty, like so:

```yaml
paths:
  # Valid
  /test/{foo}: {}
  /test/{foo}/{bar}: {}
```

In all other cases (i.e. when your path items have content), you need matching `{<identifiers>}` and parameter objects. For example, the following are errors:

```yaml
paths:
  /test/{foo}:
    get:
      parameters: []  # Error - missing path parameter definition
      ...

  /test:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: path    # Error - a path parameter is defined, but is not included in the endpoint path
          name: foo
          ...
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you, that makes life a lot easier!